# Localisation of sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, multi-geo

For legal reasons, I would like to know if cloud document servers are in Quebec. if not, are they in Canada?

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 is now Multie-Geo Location supported. Yes it has the dataCenter in the canada. [you can check it here](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/multi-geo-capabilities).

Here are the list of all available data centers:  `Australia, Asia Pacific, **Canada**, European Union, France, India, Japan, Korea, United Kingdom, and United States.`

**Note:** `Multi-Geo is currently available to customers with a minimum of 5,000 Office 365 services subscriptions. Contact your Microsoft representative for details.`

Answer (score 0):

Are you the Tenant / Global admin? If so, go to the https://admin.microsoft.com/ site, click Settings and the Organization Profile. Scroll down and find:

[image]

Or in the portal click Support and make a Service Request to ask for the exact location.